# How to set up Spring Boot datasource URL from AWS AppConfig?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-app-config

So the title says pretty much it all. I have a spring-boot based Microservices and I need to supply everything which usually goes to `application.properties` via AWS AppConfig. How can I do this? I've created a sample project, but how can I do this for the database URL?

Answer (score 0):

If I had correctly understand the question then you need to configure the application properties through the AWS Config. On high level, AWS Config has `Configuration Profile` where you can store the configurations. The config profile can be in YML, JSON or text document format. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/what-is-appconfig.html) is the official documentation of AWS config.